# Переменные. Присваивание значений множеству переменных в цикле

Tags: c++

Всем привет. У меня намечается проект по с++, но пока я только
 подготавливаюсь к нему(пишу библиотеки). Но вопрос в том, как реализовать следующее:

```
//Есть переменные от name1-name12(string)  
int x = 1;
while(x < 13)
{
    namex = "test"; //на месте х должно быть число, объявленное в начале кода
    x++;
}
```

То есть мне надо, чтобы в цикле на месте х(после name) было число.
Прошу тапками не кидаться, ибо я начинающий :3

Comment: Сделайте массив строк.

Comment: Используйте массивы или коллекции с доступом по индексу.

Comment: А можно по-подробней?

Comment: http://cppstudio.com/post/389/ http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector в общем, берите книгу в руки...

Comment: Спасибо огромное)

Comment: Самое главное - это обходить стороной #define :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае придется столкнуться с такой вещью, как массивы. Проще говоря, массив - это множество ячеек. Каждая из них имеет свой номер и значение. Соответственно, для обращения к ячейке необходимо это значение знать.

Массив объявляется почти так, как и другие переменные. Вот шаблон:

```
<тип данных> <имя переменной> [<количество значений>];//объявление без инициализации (присвоения значения)
<тип данных> <имя переменной> [<количество значений>] = {<значение 1>, <значение 2>, <значение 3>, <значение 4>...};//объявление и инициализация
```

Пример кода:

```
int a [10];
int b [4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Теперь поговорим о том, как обращаться к ячейке.

```
<имя переменной> [<индекс>] = <значение>;
```

Важно! Нумерация начинается с нуля! Это значит, что если будет создан массив из 10 элементов, то будут элементы с индексами от 0 до 9. Пример кода:

```
c [n] = 4;
```

Индексом может быть как переменная, так и число. Это очень полезно в циклах. Также нужно знать - если Вы создали переменную из 10 значений, то их количество уже никак не поменять. Также совсем необязательно устанавливать размер массива. Пример программы, принимающей и выводящей числа с помощью массивов:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "Введите размер массива: ";
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    const int n = a;
    int arr [n];//создаем массив из n элементов
    cout << "Введите Ваш массив:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)//не забываем - нумерация ячеек идет с нуля!
    {
        cin >> arr [i];//обращение и запись в ячейку
    }
    cout << "Ваш массив: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {
        cout << arr [i] << " ";//чтение из ячейки
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Результат выполнения программы:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: отличное решение! Пусть вопрощающий подолбиться  с тем почему код `int arr [n];` (который являеться расширением от gcc) не компилиться.

Comment: Да? У меня везде работало ;)

Comment: посмотрите ответы здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/622243/Динамическое-выделение-памяти-с

Comment: @AndrioSkur, исправил на *const int*.

Comment: добавление const никак не поможет. Размер массива должен быть константой времени компиляции.